# How does the value (-1 or 1 or 0) returned by CompareTo() in C# actually sort the numbers

Tags: c#, compareto

A simple version of my query:

I have a list [10,500,49,3, 8585, 6726, 721661,7623, 76].

I apply list.Sort() and i get the sorted list [3,10,49,76,500,6726,7623,8585,721661].

If i try to understand the logic beneath, I can see that a compare to function is being used which returns either 1, -1 or 0 based on the comparison. Now what i want to understand and what these linked question fail to answer is how based on whether 1 or 0 or -1 is returned is the sorting of 10,500,49,.. is being done. So, if  500 > 10 returns 1 how is the swapping done? Where is the swapping being done? What is the logic used for it? Is the Sort Method implementing the logic for swapping?

---

This question is not duplicate. I want to understand the logic of the sort method in C#. Please go through the complete question in order to understand my query. Do not mark it as duplicate and do not make Stack Overflow such a harsh community. I am asking only if i was not able to find the answer anywhere.

I want to know how the below code returning 1, 0, -1 actually sorts a list.

```
public int CompareTo(Employee other)
{
    if (this.Salary > other.Salary)
        return 1;
    else if (this.Salary < other.Salary)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

List<Employee> lstNewEmp = new List<Employee>();
lstEmp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 5, Name = "k", Experience = 3, Salary = 425000 });
lstEmp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 6, Name = "u", Experience = 4, Salary = 450000 });
lstEmp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 7, Name = "t", Experience = 6, Salary = 425000 });
lstEmp.Add(new Employee() { Id = 8, Name = "z", Experience = 3, Salary = 700000 });

foreach(var i in lstEmp)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before Sorting: " + " "+ "Emp No: " + lstEmp.IndexOf(i) + " " + "Employee Name " + i.Name);
}    
lstemp.Sort();

foreach(var i in lstEmp)
{
    Console.WriteLine("After Sorting: " + " "+ "Emp No: " + lstEmp.IndexOf(i) + " " + "Employee Name " + i.Name);
}
```

To explain my query further, this function should return 1 if current instance Salary is greater than the salary of the instance we compare it with. But if I use the Sort() function (which uses the above CompareTo() logic to actually sort the list) on the list of employees, I do not get the return 1 or 0 or -1 instead I get a sorted list. This is what I am unable to understand. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Sort does not return number. its a method in which it calls the `CompareTo` method to get the comparison result (as number) so it can use that number to sort the list.

Comment: Just asserting "This question is not duplicate." doesn't make it so. The first question that was linked as a possible duplicate I don't agree with, but the second "Internal working of the Sort() and CompareTo() methods" does seem to contain a comprehensive explanation. If it's not adequate, please quote from the question/answers there and explain what they *still fail to make clear*

Comment: Just asserting "This question is duplicate." doesn't make it so. These questions fail to explain how the list is actually being sorted. It is fine that logic returns 1 when the value in the current instance is greater than the value in the instance being passed in compare to function. Go through my full question, do your research and then think whether what i have asked is duplicate?

Comment: I have made a final edit please go through that. If you still think this is duplicate, God bless America

Comment: Of course, duplicate or not it isn't on-topic on SO.

Comment: how come it isn't on-topic?